# Why my shipsSunk property in the model object is 9 instead of 3?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am practicing Javascript by creating a battleship game, and I am trying to display the user a message when it finishes the game.

```
if (hit && model.shipsSunk === model.numShips) {
                view.displayMessage("You Sank all my battleships, in " + this.guesses + " guesses");
            }
```

But nothing happens and when I console.log the value of shipsSunk is equal 9 instead of 3 (numShips = 3, so I need that exact number to be able to run the code above).

```
var view = {
    displayMessage: function(msg) {
        var messageArea = document.getElementById("messageArea");
        messageArea.innerHTML = msg;
    },
    displayHit: function(location) {
        var cell = document.getElementById(location);
        cell.setAttribute("class", "hit");
    },
    displayMiss: function(location) {
        var cell = document.getElementById(location);
        cell.setAttribute("class", "miss");
    }
};

var model = {
    boardSize: 7,
    numShips: 3,
    shiplength: 3,
    shipsSunk: 0,
    ships: [
            {locations: ["06", "16", "26"], hits: ["", "", ""] },
            {locations: ["24", "34", "44"], hits: ["", "", ""] },
            {locations: ["10", "11", "12"], hits: ["", "", ""] }],
    fire: function(guess) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++) {
            var ship = this.ships[i];
            var index = ship.locations.indexOf(guess);
            if (index >= 0) {
                ship.hits[index] = "hit";
                view.displayHit(guess);
                view.displayMessage("HIT!");
                if (this.isSunk(ship)) {
                    view.displayMessage("You sank my battleship!");
                    this.shipsSunk++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        view.displayMiss(guess);
        view.displayMessage("You missed.");
        return false;
    },
    isSunk: function(ship) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.shipLength; i++) {
            if (ship.hits[i] !== "hit") {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

var controller = {
    guesses: 0,
    processGuess: function(guess) {
        var location = parseGuess(guess);
        if (location) {
            this.guesses++;
            var hit = model.fire(location);
            if (hit && model.shipsSunk === model.numShips) {
                view.displayMessage("You Sank all my battleships, in " + this.guesses + " guesses");
            }
        }
    } 
};
function parseGuess(guess) {
    var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
    if (guess === null || guess.length !== 2) {
        alert("Oops, please enter a letter and a number on the board.");
    }  else {
        firstChar = guess.charAt(0);
        var row = alphabet.indexOf(firstChar);
        var column = guess.charAt(1);

        if (isNaN(row) || isNaN(column)) {
            alert("Oops, that isn't on the board.");
        } else if (row < 0 || row >= model.boardSize || column < 0 || column >= model.boardSize) {
            alert("Oops, that's off the board!");
        } else {
            return row + column;
        }
    }
    return null;
};

controller.processGuess("A0");

controller.processGuess("A6");
controller.processGuess("B6");
controller.processGuess("C6");

controller.processGuess("C4");
controller.processGuess("D4");
controller.processGuess("E4");

controller.processGuess("B0");
controller.processGuess("B1");
controller.processGuess("B2");

console.log(model.shipsSunk);
```

Comment: I can win this game in just 5 turns. My guesses are 10, 11, 12, 12, 12. Three ships sunken. GG! There are more logical errors in your code than you might think.

Comment: Yes, I haven't code that yet but I just need to see why shipsSunk property keeps increasing after 3.

Comment: I updated the question because I am not really sure where is the mistake. So I added all the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question falls into category: *reading the answer is followed by facepalm* a.k.a. *stupid mistake*. The answer is simple. In your model you define `shiplength: 3` with lower-case `l` and in your `isSunk` function you read the value of `this.shipLength` with upper-case `L`. Fix one or the other and the code will work as expected.